Predicting contract renewals with a linear regression model
Good day all
I have an idea where I want to predict contract renewals over time for a service based company. Essentially, taking the total amount of times a customer decides to renew their contracts with the service provider and the independent variables would be the volume of services performed by the provider. Essentially, trying to find which services most positively, negatively, or don’t impact total contract renewals.
I was thinking of making the renewal dependent variable as Years in contract renewal. If the customer decided to renew the contract for 5 years(by signing a 5 year contract), I am treating that as “5” in the dependent variable column. If a customer decided to renew for a 1 year contract, that would be a 1, for example.
My concern is I typically don’t like to use time as a dependent variable as this isn’t a duration study, per se, it’s a continuous sales study. Would anyone here model this a bit differently?
